# Styling 'Change Password' standard page

Tags: community

I would like to change the 'Change your password' label from the standard change password page. I can do it with CSS but I don't know where I can put these styles. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the standard pages, but you can create a custom Visualforce page for Change Password and set it in the Administration > Login and Registration section of your community.

See the [help page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_password_management.htm&type=5)

> You can customize Forgot Password and Change Password pages from the
>   Workspaces Administration Login & Registration page. Or you can create
>   custom password pages in Visualforce. You can also customize the
>   default password templates in Visualforce.